# Tool selection for performance testing

Tags: performance-testing

Would like to check which tool is the best to do performance testing.

Currently we have to to decide between these two tools open source tools

either K6 or Jmeter .

K6 is the latest tool which got popularized ,  would like to know the advantages and disadvantages between these two.

Answer (score 1):

The tool selection itself doesn't really matter as long as you possess necessary qualifications (in case of k6 it's [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) knowledge) and the tool fulfils your requirements (protocols, number of virtual users to simulate, etc).

Overall process of load testing tools selection is highlighted in [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/).

Personally I would go for Apache JMeter mainly because:

1. k6 supports only [HTTP protocol](https://docs.k6.io/docs/protocols) and JMeter provides more even [out of the box](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and much more with the [plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/)
2. k6 can be executed [only on one machine](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/140) and JMeter can be run in [Distributed Mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) which might be a dealbreaker when it comes to high loads

Comment: Thanks for the response Dmitri.. But have an opinion with the second point , seems K6 supports distributed testing too. Please let me know if not the case.